# Reading .vsdx(visio 2013) file using visual studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, visio

How can I read a sequence diagram using c# language in visual studio? I want to know the node information i.e how many messages are sending or receiving etc.

Answer (score 1):

There is a good KB article about that which explains in details how to manipulate .vsdx a Visio file using System.IO.Packaging and XML. Check it out:

[How to: Manipulate the Visio 2013 file format programmatically](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj649391(v=office.15).aspx)

Also, check out this blog article on MSDN:

[10 tips for developers working with the Visio VSDX file format](http://blogs.office.com/2013/01/29/10-tips-for-developers-working-with-the-visio-vsdx-file-format/)